# Simulate Middle Mouse Click on hyperlink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to simulate a middle mouse click on a hyperlink?
I have the following code, for showing a list of succeeded imports of products:

```
<tr>
   <td>
    @{
       int counter = 0;
       foreach (int productid in Model.SucceededProductIdsList)
       {
         <ul>
         <li>-------------------------------------------------------</li>
         <li><b>@String.Format("ProductID: {0}", Convert.ToString(productid))</b></li>
         <li><b>@String.Format("{0}", Model.SucceededProductManufacturerIdsList[counter])</b></li>
         <li><b><a href="http://www.MyWebshop.com/Admin/Product/Edit/@productid" target="_blank">Show Product</a></b></li>
         </ul>
         counter++;
       }
     }
 </td>
```

Above code gives the admin of the web shop a list of all products that succeeded to import. I added in a hyperlink to the imported product, so it's easier for the user to directly find and if needed edit the product.

Next code shows the link to a product:

```
<li><b><a href="http://www.MyWebshop.com/Admin/Product/Edit/@productid" target="_blank">Show Product</a></b></li>
```

**Question**

I used `target="_blank"`, so the page opens in a new tab, however the current tab of the user, changes to the new tab. That is ***not*** what I want.
I want the page to open in a new tab, but the users current tab should still be the same and ***not*** the new tab.(Same behavior as when a user clicks on the link with the Middle Mouse Button)

Is there any HTML or C#/Razor allowing me to do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is nothing you can do. This behaviour depends purely on browser. In some browsers (firefox for instance) you can configure that behaviour. 
Tab is browser being, and you don't have any reliable method to control active tab from web page level.

Comment: Thanks, do you think something can be done using Javascript? Changing a onclick?

Comment: I don't think so. There is `window.focus()` method in JS, but it doesn't work. Actually this is good thing if you think about that. Allowing switching tabs/windows from JS would introduce potential security issue - for example some harmful page could steal your focus when you're typing password.